# Azure Cloud Service to serve/render bitmap images via ashx?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, handler, cloud-hosting

So I've got my first Azure Cloud Service Up and running. A hello world of sorts. Before I dig in I want to ask a few high level questions since its seems somewhat foriegn to me.

I'm developing in vs 2012 4.5.

I've got this NON Cloud solution that works from dev at home, but not on Godaddy hosting because it requires Full Trust Permissions due to a WebBrowser Class.

1. First I'd like to know **will Full Trust  will be an issue on  Azure Cloud Services**.
2. What will it take to turn asp.net web project with a cs class and an ashx handler into a cloud service. I'd like to secure only by restricting what IP addresses can run it.  Below is an image of what the Azure Cloud solution generated and **I'm wondering how much of this I can do away with** and where to squeeze my solution in.:
3. I'm wondering **how cost effective** will be to host my service on the cloud if what's basically doing is turning urls into images with a watermark.  It's using WebBrowser, Graphhic, Bitmap, and Thread classes.  It **maybe be 100 requests** a day and I'll need to find a way so that robots are not costing me.

[image: VS 2012 Cloud Service]

Answer (score 1):

You are asking too many and to broad questions!

> First I'd like to know will Full Trust will be an issue on Azure Cloud
>   Services.

No. Not at all. Azure Cloud Service by default runs in Full Trust.

> What will it take to turn asp.net web project with a cs class and an
>   ashx handler into a cloud service. I'd like to secure only by
>   restricting what IP addresses can run it. Below is an image of what
>   the Azure Cloud solution generated and I'm wondering how much of this
>   I can do away with and where to squeeze my solution in.:

The same work that it would take to run it on your own IIS server. Azure Web Role is basically a virtual machine with Full IIS installed on it. And you can shape the IIS the way you want.

> I'm wondering how cost effective will be to host my service on the
>   cloud if what's basically doing is turning urls into images with a
>   watermark. It's using WebBrowser, Graphhic, Bitmap, and Thread
>   classes. It maybe be 100 requests a day and I'll need to find a way so
>   that robots are not costing me.

Do your math based on the [Price Calculator](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=full).

Comment: Thank You, but I just can't start ripping code out of the hello world solution. Somehow my solution needs to factor in the Webrole and what do we do with AccountController and Controller? and it's a dumb/noob question but the home page appears to be index.cshtml now. Taking a first step here and don't see how to wire it up I guess.